# how to enable my code to skip over certain code when the input by the user is a specific option

Tags: java

Hi I was wondering if someone could help me make it so when I choose an option in my code when the program runs, it skips all the other options that weren't chosen and only uses the code inputted by the user. So only the specific parts in the code should be printed but I don't know how to skip over code. There is probably things I should remove and then things I should add but I need help.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Test
{
    static Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );      

    public static void main(String[] args)             
    {                     
        //Variables
        String Option;  
        int a;
        int Base;
        int Height; 
        int Length;
        int Width;
        int Radius;
        int r;
        int b;
        double Area;

        //Menu
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Area Calculator");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1. Square");
        System.out.println("2. Rectangle");        
        System.out.println("3. Circle");        
        System.out.println("4. Triangle"); 
        System.out.println("5. Quit");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of the shape you would like to calculate the area for.");
        Option=input.next();  
    }

    public static void Sqaure(String[] args)  

    {     
        System.out.println("Please enter the length of one side.");
        int a=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the length of one side.");
        double area = a*a;
        System.out.println("The area of the given shape is " + area + " square units.");                   
    }

    public static void Rectangle(String[] args)

    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the length.");
        int Length=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the width.");
        int Width=input.nextInt();
        double area = Length*Width;
        System.out.println("The area of the given shape is " + area + " square units.");                  
    }

    public static void Circle(String[] args)

    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the radius.");
        int r=input.nextInt();
        double Radius = r*r;
        double area = Math.PI * Radius;         
        System.out.println("The area of the given shape is " + area + " square units.");        
    }


    {        
        System.out.println("Please enter the base length.");
        int b=input.nextInt();
        double Base = b * .5;
        System.out.println("Please enter the height lenth.");
        int Height=input.nextInt();
        double area = Base * Height;
        System.out.println("The area of the given shape is " + area + " square units.");
    } 

}
```

Comment: You should do a Google search for `if else` or `conditionals`.

Comment: a swtich would be good I think

Comment: @ScaryWombat Hi thanks for the suggestion. I learned about those but haven't used them. Could you let me know what they do and where they should go? Thank you

Comment: [google](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) is your friend

Comment: I have implemented your condition with switch case example and make a slight correction in your code also.

Answer (score 0):

So, it is clear to me you're very new with Java and you're learning! So I went ahead and made a complete working version of what you are trying to do.

Although it is a simple program Ill go through what each section does.

### Prompt Method

Asks the user which area they want to find, this method has the direct answer to your question in the form of a series of if/if else statements. It gets the input from the user and then goes through the series of if/if else statements, seeing if the value entered matches any of them, if it does then it runs that section of code and skips the rest. If a number other then 1-4 is entered, it quits the program (see the else statement), [see this page for more info on if statements.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) I opted for a bunch of if statements but there is a better, cleaner way, but it is a little confusing if you are brand new, [see here to learn about those.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

### Area Methods

These are all pretty much the same except for he way they calculate the areas. They first prompt the user for the required measurements for that shape and assign those entered values to variables, then it prints out the resulting area after running the values through a calculation, then the program stops.

### Main Method

All the main method is doing is calling prompt, that keeps it clean, you don't really ever want to do anything but call other methods or create objects in the main method, so most people put the nitty gritty somewhere else and call it.

### Below is the working code

Go ahead and paste into a doc and run it, just be aware that I did not bother to add any error catching to keep it simple so keep it to whole numbers without decimals (also called ints, eg. 1, 2, 4, not 4.3, 5.4, etc.)

Side note:

In your methods you have (String args[]) in the brackets, this is not needed, in fact it will cause trouble, that is only used in the main method and is a relatively advanced way of providing input to the program, for now you can keep to leaving the brackets empty.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Area
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
  prompt(); //Calls prompt method
}

//Prompt Method

public static void prompt()
{
  int option;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  //Ask the user which shape they want to find the area of
  System.out.println("Select from the following shapes to calulate the area:");
  System.out.println("Rectangle -- 1\nCircle    -- 2\nTriangle  -- 3\nQuit      -- 4\n");
  System.out.print("Your option: ");
  option = input.nextInt();
  System.out.println();
  
  //THIS IS THE PART THAT DIRECTLY PERTAINS TO YOUR QUESTION

  if(option == 1)
  {
     rectangle();
  }
  
  else if(option == 2)
  {
     circle();
  }
  
  else if(option == 3)
  {
     triangle();
  }
  
  else
  {
     System.out.println("Program stopped by user"); //For stopping the program when they want to quit instead
     System.exit(0);
  }
}

//Rectangle Method

public static void rectangle()
{
  double h;
  double b;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println("RECTANGLE");
  System.out.print("Enter Height: ");
  h = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.print("Enter Base: ");
  b = input.nextDouble();
  
  System.out.print("\nArea of Rectangle = " + (h*b) + "\n");
}

//Circle Method

public static void circle()
{
  double pi = 3.14;
  double radius;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println("CIRCLE");
  System.out.print("Enter radius: ");
  radius = input.nextDouble();
  
  System.out.print("\nArea of Circle = " + (pi*(radius*radius)) + "\n");
}

//Triangle Method

public static void triangle()
{
  double h;
  double b;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println("TRIANGLE");
  System.out.print("Enter Height: ");
  h = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.print("Enter Base: ");
  b = input.nextDouble();
  
  System.out.print("\nArea of Triangle = " + ((h*b)/2) + "\n");

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Test
{
    static Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );      

    public static void main(String[] args)             
    {                     
        //Variables
        String Option;  
        int a;
        int Base;
        int Height; 
        int Length;
        int Width;
        int Radius;
        int r;
        int b;
        double Area;
        String [] inputString  = new String [50]; 

        //Menu
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Area Calculator");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1. Square");
        System.out.println("2. Rectangle");        
        System.out.println("3. Circle");        
        System.out.println("4. Triangle"); 
        System.out.println("5. Quit");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of the shape you would like to calculate the area for.");
        Option=input.next();
        switch (Option) {
                    case "1":  Sqaure(inputString);
                             break;
                    case "2":  Rectangle(inputString);
                             break;
                    case "3":  Circle(inputString);
                             break;
                    default: someExtraFig(inputString);
                             break;
                }
    }

    public static void Sqaure(String[] args)  

    {     
        System.out.println("Please enter the length of one side.");
        int a=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the length of one side.");
        double area = a*a;
        System.out.println("The area of the given shape is " + area + " square units.");                   
    }

    public static void Rectangle(String[] args)

    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the length.");
        int Length=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the width.");
        int Width=input.nextInt();
        double area = Length*Width;
        System.out.println("The area of the given shape is " + area + " square units.");                  
    }

    public static void Circle(String[] args)

    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the radius.");
        int r=input.nextInt();
        double Radius = r*r;
        double area = Math.PI * Radius;         
        System.out.println("The area of the given shape is " + area + " square units.");        
    }

  public static void someExtraFig(String ...s)
    {        
        System.out.println("Please enter the base length.");
        int b=input.nextInt();
        double Base = b * .5;
        System.out.println("Please enter the height lenth.");
        int Height=input.nextInt();
        double area = Base * Height;
        System.out.println("The area of the given shape is " + area + " square units.");
    } 

}
```